# nativescript webview not working inside a popup

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webview, nativescript, nativescript-vue

Here is my popup code:

```
<template>
  <frame id="popup">
    <page actionBarHidden="true">
      <StackLayout>
        <WebView :src="html" />
      </StackLayout>
    </page>
  </frame>
</template>

<script>
  import circleBtn from "./circleBtn.vue";
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        html: `
<div>hellow</div>
<video width="400" controls>
<source src="~/assets/videos/color-festival.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
`,
      };
    },
  };
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

Here is how I open my popup:

```
  toVideo() {
    this.$showModal(nsVideo, {fullscreen: true});
  },
```

When I open the pupup nothing is shown.
How can I fix it?
I don't actually need to use the webview itself. I only want to show a video in a crossplatform way, I tried `nativescript-videoview` but it worked so bad in popup. So I came to webview but this is also not working. I really don't know what to do anymore.

**Solution:**
It appears that my phone needed to get connected and disconnected to internet for webview to work:-////! Eventho I was using a local file! So I connected and disconnected once and changed the `~` in my path to `.` and now everything works.

Comment: Are you testing with iOS or Android? Doesn't work with a remote video?

Comment: I'm testing on android.

Comment: It doesn't even show the div!!

Comment: Please share a Playground Sample, it works perfectly fine on my end, except I did my quick test with remote video.

Comment: I tried to do a remote, so I connected my phone to internet and now the local file kinda works to, it doesn't play the video but at least it renders the page etc.

Comment: seems like my phone needed to fetch something from the internet to have this to work:-/ it's very strange, I just connected and then disconnected my phone and now it's working, it only can't find the local file, I don't know how I should specify path for it. the path I've put here works with nativescript-videoplayer. but I assume ~ is not the app folter anymore in a webview, do you know how I should specify path?

Comment: replaced the ~ with . and now it works. thank you so much.

Comment: We view does not know what is ~, try using absolute path.